# Encontrar la palabra mas larga de una lista de strings en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Hola necesito un programa que: dado una frase definida por el usuario retorne la palabra mas larga de la frase. Por ejemplo si al frase fuese: "hola que haces" en este caso imprimiria la palabra "haces" porque es la mas larga.

He intentato hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
frase = input("Frases: ")

s = frase.split(" ")

string = ""

for x in s:
    if s[0] < s[1]:
            string + str(s)
            print(string)


 print(string)
```

No me funciona nada y estoy perdido

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo spliteando por espacios vacíos tu frase y encontrando la palabra mas larga en una lista a partir del método `max()`

```
frase = input("Frases: ")
palabra_mas_larga =  max(frase.split(' '), key=len)
```